# Fazer a Média em Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma tabela que por linha está a realizar um cálculo e a colocar o resultado na coluna dos resultados. O objetivo é que agora a no final em três cubos apareçam médias consoante os resultados obtidos e não sei como chamar esses resultados.

Vejam este código:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12" method="POST">
           <?php
              if ($error) {
                  echo '<div class="errorWrap"><strong>ERROR</strong> : ' . htmlentities($error) . '</div>';
              } else if ($msg) {
                  echo '<div class="succWrap"><strong>SUCESSO</strong>:' . htmlentities($msg) . '</div>';
              } ?>
           <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id = "AvalExpec" type = "tel" class = "validate" name = "AvalExpec">
              <label for="avalexp" class="active">Adicionar Avaliação Expectativas</label>
           </div>
           <table id="example" class="striped">
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivos</th>
                    <th>
                       <center>Data Inicial </center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <center>Data Final </center>
                    </th>
                    <th>Avaliação Inicial</th>
                    <th>
                       <center>Meta </center>
                    </th>
                    <th>Avaliação Intercalar</th>
                    <th>Avaliação Final</th>
                    <th>Resultado (%)</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivo 1</th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
                          <label for="datainicio"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
                          <label for="datafim"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avInicial1" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                             onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
                          <label for="avinicial"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="meta1" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                             name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
                          <label for="meta"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
                          <label for="avintercalar"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avFinal1" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
                          <label for="avfinal"></label>       
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input disabled id="resultado1" name="ResultadoUni" />
                          <label for="resultadouni"></label>  
                       </div>
                    </th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivo 2</th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
                          <label for="datainicio"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
                          <label for="datafim"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avInicial2" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                             onchange="calculaResultado(2)">
                          <label for="avinicial"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="meta2" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                             name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(2)">
                          <label for="meta"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
                          <label for="avintercalar"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avFinal2" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(2)">
                          <label for="avfinal"></label> 
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input disabled id="resultado2"/>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivo 3</th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
                          <label for="datainicio"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
                          <label for="datafim"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avInicial3" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                             onchange="calculaResultado(3)">
                          <label for="avinicial"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="meta3" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                             name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(3)">
                          <label for="meta"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
                          <label for="avintercalar"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avFinal3" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(3)">
                          <label for="avfinal"></label> 
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input disabled id="resultado3"/>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivo 4</th>
                    <th>
                       <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
                       <label for="datainicio"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
                          <label for="datafim"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avInicial4" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                             onchange="calculaResultado(4)">
                          <label for="avinicial"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="meta4" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                             name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(4)">
                          <label for="meta"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
                          <label for="avintercalar"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avFinal4" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(4)">
                          <label for="avfinal"></label> 
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input disabled id="resultado4"/>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivo 5</th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
                          <label for="datainicio"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
                          <label for="datafim"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avInicial5" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                             onchange="calculaResultado(5)">
                          <label for="avinicial"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="meta5" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                             name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(5)">
                          <label for="meta"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
                          <label for="avintercalar"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avFinal5" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(5)">
                          <label for="avfinal"></label> 
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input disabled id="resultado5"/>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivo 6</th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
                          <label for="datainicio"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
                       <label for="datafim"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avInicial2" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                             onchange="calculaResultado(6)">
                          <label for="avinicial"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="meta2" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                             name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(6)">
                          <label for="meta"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
                          <label for="avintercalar"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avFinal6" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(6)">
                          <label for="avfinal"></label> 
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input disabled id="resultado6"/>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Objetivo 7</th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
                          <label for="datainicio"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
                          <label for="datafim"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avInicial2" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                             onchange="calculaResultado(7)">
                          <label for="avinicial"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="meta2" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                             name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(7)">
                          <label for="meta"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
                          <label for="avintercalar"></label>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input id="avFinal7" type="text" class="validate"
                             autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(7)">
                          <label for="avfinal"></label> 
                       </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                          <input disabled id="resultado7"/>
                       </div>
                    </th>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12 m3">
                 <div class="card-panel teal #263238 blue-grey darken-4" class="center-align">
                    <input disabled id="ConcretizaObj"/>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col s12 m3 ">
                 <div class="card-panel teal #263238 blue-grey darken-4" class="center-align">
                    <input disabled id="ObjDefinidos"/>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col s12 m3 ">
                 <div class="card-panel teal #263238 blue-grey darken-4" class="center-align">
                    <input disabled id="ObjAtingidos"/>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col s12 m3 ">
                 <div class="card-panel teal #263238 blue-grey darken-4" class="center-align">
                    <input disabled id="TotalAlcancados"/>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <center><input type="submit" value="Submeter"
              onclick="javascript: location.href='pii.php';"
              class="btn #ff7043 deep-orange lighten-1"/></center>
     </div>
     </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </main>
  <div class="left-sidebar-hover"></div>
  <script>
     function calculaResultado(x){        
         console.log(x);
         a = document.getElementById('avInicial' + x).value;
         b = document.getElementById('meta' + x).value;
         c = document.getElementById('avFinal' + x).value;

         let resultado = ((c*100)/b);

         if(b === c){
             resultado = 100; //100%
         } else if (a > c) {
             resultado = 0; // 0%
         } else {
             resultado = parseInt(resultado);
         }

         document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value =  resultado; 
     }

     function {
         console.log(x)
         resultados = document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value;

         let media = 
     }
  </script>
```

basicamente o resultado para já está assim:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

O que eu pretendo é que nas 4 caixas escuras no fundo, na primeira apareça a médias dos valores obtidos na coluna dos resultados.

Comment: Apenas como dica, este não é o local para ajudas "urgentes".

Comment: sou html está gigante, edite e coloque só o que é relevante para a pergunta, difícil ler assim

Answer (score 1):

Para que na primeira caixa apareça a médias dos valores obtidos nas colunas dos resultados.
Crie a seguinte função:

```
function calculaMediaFinal () {
    var soma = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) { 
        soma += parseInt(document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value, 10); 
    }
    var media = soma / 7;

    var inputCuboMedia = document.getElementById('ConcretizaObj');
    //se sua regra de negócio permitir casas decimais use por exemplo media.toFixed(2); ao invés de parseInt
    inputCuboMedia.value = parseInt(media, 10);
}
```

e a chame no final da função calculaResultado:

```
function calculaResultado(x){        
        //[...código da função calculaResultado...]

        //na última linha dessa função chame 
        calculaMediaFinal();        
     }
```